# Fade in on scrolling down

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to fade in a navbar logo the moment a user scrolls past a banner. I do not want to show the logo on both places at the same time due to redundancy sake. The navbar is made with Bootstrap 3.1. This is what I have right now to make the navbar stick the moment I scroll past it:

```
$('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height()-$('#nav').height()
      }
}); 

$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav' })

$('.scroll-top').click(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
})

$('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  var posi = $(link).offset().top+20;
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:posi},700);
})
```

My question is; How do I modify this piece of code to fade in an image (fast) with an HTML `id of "navbarlogo"` when the scrollspy hits the target #nav? I am all very new to this.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Did you take a look at css3 animations? If you define an animation to an object it will occur only when the element is first visible. Take a look at: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention in your question that you are using jQuery and also which plugins you use to make it easier for others to determine if this question might hold and answer for them.

With that said, if you are using [John Smarts Scrollspy plugin](https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy) then you can write it like this:

```js
$('#nav').on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
    $('#navbarlogo').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#nav').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
    $('#navbarlogo').fadeOut(500);
});
```

500 means 500ms as in half a second.